# Spring app cant find hbm.xml mapping file

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I am working on a spring mvc app using hibernate and I am having some trouble compiling and running my code.

This is because it cannot find my FileObject.hbm.xml whenever I try to create a session factory bean.

my bean looks like this

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1"></property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>FileObject.hmb.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And the FileObject.hmb.xml resides in the root of my WAR folder. I have tried to move this file to different folders including the actual src folder and providing the correct path in the session factory but it still gives me a FileNotFoundException.

Is this because java doesnt recognise a hello.hmb.xml type of file? Most if not all file formats are like this: name.extension

hibernate mapping files seems to be different though

**Follow-up:** As I have noted before, I have tried to put my .hbm.xml in numerous places including the src directory and still wont work.

My project structure is similar to this:

[image: project structure]
<sub>(source: [springsource.org](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/images/dir-structure-endp1.png))</sub>

I have tried to put the file inside the root dir of war, WEB-INF, classes and as said before, in my actual src directory.

I never knew it was this much hassle just to get hibernate and spring running successfully.

Comment: is that a typo? "hmb.xml" instead of "hbm.xml"

Comment: hi yes thats a typo. im my code its hbm

Comment: *I have tried to put the file inside the root dir of war, WEB-INF, classes* This is not a random choice, mapping files must be on the classpath (i.e. under `WEB-INF/classes` in the war) as everybody pointed out. That's just how things work.

Answer (score 1):

MappingResources can only receive paths relative to your classpath.

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=87988

Comment: I did and the OP is having a different exception then me. my exception is that it simply cant find the file ie FileNotFoundException.

Comment: @jonney can you update the question to reflect excactly where the hbm file is and what you have in your configuration file

Answer (score 0):

If the .hbm.xml files are in a directory tree in your CLASSPATH, try putting the path starting from the root of the CLASSPATH:

```
<value>foo/bar/persistence/hibernate/FileObject.hmb.xml</value>
```

Directory path I use is just an example.